# Ban "john" as a tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed ([when asking a question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/596)) that we might have an issue with using the tag "john". It is too vague, since it could be used for multiple reasons. I suggest we **ban it** and replace it with one of these:

- john-book
- john-apostle
- 1-john
- 2-john
- 3-john
- john-the-baptist

Does the community agree?

Comment: Great idea. Some of those are already in use.

Comment: How does that work for the user who tries using "john" as the tag?  I do agree, though.  It'd help when trying to find questions on a specific John.

Comment: I kinda like the tag john....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would suggest that instead of "john-book" we use [gospel-of-john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gospel-of-john). In fact this could be done for all the four gospels. [gospel-of-luke](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gospel-of-luke) and [luke-apostle](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luke-apostle), etc.

Comment: +1 for **gospel-of-foo** tags.

Comment: +1 me too on gospel-of tags (but who is foo? :-) :-)

Comment: @Ollie. Foo is a metasyntactic variable.

Comment: @user116 The Gospel of Foo is a lesser-known apocryphal gospel.

Comment: Can I suggest "john-gospel" as a tag (possibly a synonym) so that when people start typing "john" they get "john-gospel" as a suggestion.

Comment: @djclayworth nice thinking but the SE engine already shows and completes tags starting after dash breaks so such hacking for function is unnecessary. We can go ahead and just optimize for readability.

Answer (score 5):

The easy way to do this is to synonymize [john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john) with [john-apostle](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-apostle) (meaning the former will be replaced with the latter when used). If incorrect tagging becomes a problem, we could look at banning it of course, but at this early stage it *seems* like this will be the most likely use for it.

Answer (score 5):

Wait a sec though. I know you didn't suggest this, but if we synonomize [john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john) with [john-presbyter](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-presbyter) [john-revelator](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-revelator), [john-apostle](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-apostle) then we might be making distinctions that scholarly types like to make, I but find to be a little disenchanting.

Can we just not go down that road?

If we can't ban the John tag, we can at least make it a policy to retag it right?

Comment: Retag it according to the content of the question. *Hopefully* it would be clear from that which John(s) was(were) intended...