# Apostle tag suggestion

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Inspired by the meta question [Ban "john" as a tag](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/ban-john-as-a-tag), as well as [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/was-the-apostle-peter-martyred-in-rome) on the main site, it seems that [peter](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peter) suffers almost (but not quite) as much ambiguity as the [john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john).  For this reason I propose the following:

- For all apostles, we use the [apostle-foo](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apostle-foo) tag.
- We make [foo-apostle](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foo-apostle) a synonym for [apostle-foo](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apostle-foo)
- As suggested by [Shog's answer](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/ban-john-as-a-tag/145#145) we also make [foo](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foo) a synonym for [apostle-foo](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apostle-foo) (as opposed to banning [foo](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foo))

And on a related note, this leaves room to expand a bit on for the suggestion found in [Ban "john" as a tag](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/ban-john-as-a-tag), use full book names when there is a conflict (I think there are only three):

- [1-john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1-john)
- [2-john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2-john)
- [3-john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3-john)
- [1-peter](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1-peter)
- [2-peter](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2-peter)
- [book-of-james](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-of-james) (synonym [james-book](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/james-book)?)

  The alternative here is to leave plain [james](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/james) alone for the book of James, and use [apostle-james](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apostle-james) to refer to the apostle, but I think for consistency, we should have all plain tags be synonyms to their apostle- equivalents

Comment: So most users probably won't know what to use.  Which I know I already don't.  :)

Comment: @a_hardin: This is why we use synonyms, to make that task easier.  See also [this answer](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/153/bible-tag-too-general/174#174), explaining that most people get tags wrong the first time regardless.

Comment: Important distinction: [tag:james-the-greater], [tag:james-the-lesser]

Comment: @Peter Turner: Good distinction. Should we make **james-the-greater** a synonym for **apostle-james**, since I'm sure far more questions will come about him?

Comment: Yeah, that'd be good.

Comment: @a_hardin The tag wikis should be edited to clearly identify what the tag is for. That will help a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tagging: Matthew/Mark/Luke/John](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4653/tagging-matthew-mark-luke-john)