# Different tags for book and person?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I recently asked a [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6938/why-isnt-god-mentioned-in-esther) tagged with [esther](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esther) because it was about the *book* of Esther.

However, I noticed that there are two separate tags for the person Daniel: [daniel](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daniel) and the book of Daniel: [book-of-daniel](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-of-daniel). However, it seems the former tag is being used for the book of Daniel as well.

Do we need to differentiate between the person and the book? If yes, I'll retag my question as [book-of-esther](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-of-esther). If not, can someone with the rep requirements synonymize [daniel](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daniel) and [book-of-daniel](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-of-daniel)?

Related: [Ban "john" as a tag](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/ban-john-as-a-tag)

Answer (score 4):

In both cases, the book and the character are almost identical. As such, I don't think two tags are needed. If the "book-of-" tags aren't already synonyms, I'd argue they should be.

Comment: go for it; you're the 12.1k rep guy. I'm just a lowly 500 with no synonymizing privs. :)